# How can I include an android library into an existing project?

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I've been trying to use this solution into my android project:
https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton

I tried since several hours, but I only managed to messed up with everything, forcing me to delete everything, reseting android studio, clone my project and restart from scratch.
I tried the solutions explained in android arsenal but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried to use the steps in the 'readme' file?

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the README on the git page you linked.

You need to include the following line within the dependencies block of your build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.honorato.multistatetogglebutton:multistatetogglebutton:0.2.2'
```

Then you can use the library, once you have sync'd the build.gradle (which it should immediately ask you to do).

Comment: I tried this, but then there is a problem with the namespace mstb used in the xml declaration of the widget. I guess it's supposed to be included when the library is imported or am I missing something?

Comment: Including that line should make everything work. If it doesn't, try cleaning, restarting Android Studio, rebuilding, etc.